# Sinusoids with frequencies that are random variales - What does the FFT impulse look like?

Tags: signal-processing, fft, dft

I'm currently working on a program in C++ in which I am computing the time varying FFT of a wav file. I have a question regarding plotting the results of an FFT.

Say for example I have a 70 Hz signal that is produced by some instrument with certain harmonics. Even though I say this signal is 70 Hz, it's a real signal and I assume will have some randomness in which that 70Hz signal varies. Say I sample it for 1 second at a sample rate of 20kHz. I realize the sample period probably doesn't need to be 1 second, but bear with me.

Because I now have 20000 samples, when I compute the FFT. I will have 20000 or (19999) frequency bins. Let's also assume that my sample rate in conjunction some windowing techniques minimize spectral leakage.

My question then: Will the FFT still produce a relatively ideal impulse at 70Hz? Or will there 'appear to be' spectral leakage which is caused by the randomness the original signal? In otherwords, what does the FFT look like of a sinusoid whose frequency is a random variable?

Comment: You'll need to use a window function, and the shape of the skirt around the fundamental peak will depend on your choice of window function.

Comment: Could you expand your problem, does  `w` change with time? I mean, your model is `sin(w * t)` where `w` is a constant realisation of your random variable?  or your model is `sin(w*t + phi(t))` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of the more common modulation schemes will add sidebands that carry the information in the modulation.  Depending on the amount and type of modulation with respect to the length of the FFT, the sidebands can either appear separate from the FFT peak, or just "fatten" a single peak.

Comment: In fact, all modulation schemes will increase the bandwidth, that being a result of the uncertainty principle of the Fourier transform (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Uncertainty_principle) that show that the product of the widths of the Fourier pair be fundamentally limited.

Answer (score 1):

Your spectrum will appear broadened and this happens in the real world. Look e.g for the Voight profile, which is a  Lorentizan (the result of an ideal exponential decay) convolved with a Gaussian of a certain width, the width being determined by stochastic fluctuations, e.g. Doppler effect on molecules in a gas that is being probed by a narrow-band laser.

You will not get an 'ideal' frequency peak either way. The limit for the resolution of the FFT is one frequency bin, (frequency resolution being given by the inverse of the time vector length), but even that (as @xvan pointed out) is in general broadened by the window function. If your window is nonexistent, i.e. it is in fact a square window of the length of the time vector, then you'll get spectral peaks that are convolved with a sinc function, and thus broadened.

The best way to visualize this is to make a long vector and plot a spectrogram (often shown for audio signals) with enough resolution so you can see the individual variation. The FFT of the overall signal is then the projection of the moving peaks onto the vertical axis of the spectrogram. The FFT of a given time vector does not have any time resolution, but sums up all frequencies that happen during the time you FFT. So the spectrogram (often people simply use the STFT, short time fourier transform) has at any given time the 'full' resolution, i.e. narrow lineshape that you expect. The FFT of the full time vector shows the algebraic sum of all your lineshapes and therefore appears broadened.

To sum it up there are two separate effects:
a) broadening from the window function (as the commenters 1 and 2 pointed out)
b) broadening from the effect of frequency fluctuation that you are trying to simulate and that happens in real life (e.g. you sitting on a swing while receiving a radio signal).

Finally, note the significance of @xvan's comment : `phi= phi(t)`. If the phase angle is time dependent then it has a derivative that is not zero. `dphi/dt` is a frequency shift, so your instantaneous frequency becomes   `f0 + dphi/dt`.